# How can I retain selected items after refresh in Windows Store app C# listview?

Tags: c#, windows, listview, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

I only see one unanswered question related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254997/refresh-listview-with-checked-items), so I thought I would try asking again.

I have a `ListView` that populates from a `string` array.  The reason I need to repopulate the `ListView` is because I set the foreground color on some items depending on the current time, and the only way I've found to set the foreground color is when the item is added to the `ListView`. (If there's a way to change the color of existing items that would be great, but I can't find a way.) It's frustrating that `ListView` is different in the Windows Store than in Windows desktop WPF apps.

Anyway, when items are selected the selections (checkmarks) disappear once the list is repopulated.  I've found a way to find which items are currently selected before the refresh I think by using `var selecteditems = myListView.SelectedItems;` but trying to use that to recheck the items after the refresh seems futile.  Any help is greatly appreciated as I've been racking my brains for weeks over this.  It seems it should be so simple so I'm really frustrated.

Another way I was thinking would be to do a `foreach` on each item and checking if `.IsSelected` is true, but I can't seem to associate each separate item that way.

In my mind I'm thinking do something like:

```
foreach (ListViewItem Item in ListView.Items) 
{ 
    if (Item.isselected)
        \\ do something so to remember which items are selected
}
```

Then at some point after the new `ListView` is populated, do another `foreach` and if it matches the previous selected item, select it again. However, just programmatically selecting items seems difficult in Windows 8.1 Store Apps VS2013.  It even seems `ArrayList` is no longer available now.  Why does MS have to keep changing things?

Comment: Wow. Ouch my eyes. Unless you bother to format it, I'm not going to bother reading it.

Comment: `It even seems ArrayList is no longer available now.` Umm, no? It's still there -- [MSDN ArrayList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks but that reference isn't available to me   System.Windows.Forms, i believe that is only for windows desktop apps, not windows 8.1 store apps

Comment: haha jash, that isn't how i formatted it when I wrote it, but that's how it ended up after I posted!

Comment: Well then you should have edited it to correct the formatting when you saw that it was messed up. You should have done that, not me.

Comment: sorry this is my first post on stack overflow, and actually i just did try to reformat it and when i hit save it said you already did it :) thanks!